# Java EE Soteria and Single Sign-On

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, single-sign-on

I have read the blog from [Arjan Tijms](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/p/whats-new-in-java-ee-security-api-10.html) on Java EE new Soteria Implementation. I wanted to know if this can be used to implement a single sign-on authentication module for several web applications hosted in independent servers with multiple domains. If so, can someone give some pointers on how to implement it?